# Apply binary variable to multiple records of same key in R

Tags: r, records, indicator, grepl

I have a table of doctor visits wherein there are sometimes multiple records for the same encounter key if there are multiple diagnoses, such as:

```
Enc_Key | Patient_Key |   Enc_Date   | Diag_Key
  123         789         20160512       765
  123         789         20160512       263
  123         789         20160515       493
  546         013         20160226       765      
  564         444         20160707       004
  789         226         20160707       546
  789         226         20160707       765
```

I am trying to create an indicator variable based on the value of the Diag_Key column, but I need to apply it for the entire encounter. In other word, if I get a value of "756" for the diagnoses code, then I want to apply a "1" for the indicator variable to every record that has the same Enc_Key as the record that has a Diag_Code value of 756, such as below:

```
Enc_Key | Patient_Key |   Enc_Date   | Diag_Key  | Diag_Ind
  123         789         20160512       765           1
  123         789         20160512       263           1
  123         789         20160515       493           1
  546         013         20160226       723           0
  564         444         20160707       004           0
  789         226         20160707       546           1
  789         226         20160707       765           1
```

I can't seem to figure out a way to apply this binary indicator to multiple different records. I have been using a line of code that resembles this:

```
tbl$Diag_Ind <- ifelse(grepl('765',tbl$Diag_Key),1,0)
```

but this would only assign a value of "1" to the single record with that Diag_Key value, and I'm unsure of how to apply it to the rest of the records with the same Enc_Key value

Comment: `as.integer(duplicated(tbl$Enc_Key) | duplicated(tbl$Enc_Key, fromLast = TRUE))`?

Comment: Some of the data is changing in your example and descriptions, but `ave` lets you generate a value for each group: `ave(df$Diag_Key, df$Enc_Key, FUN = function(x){any(x == 765)})` Or just group with dplyr or data.table.

Answer (score 0):

Use `==` to compare values directly and `%in%` for filtering with multiple values. For example, this will identify all `Enc_Keys` which have some `Diag_Key == 765`:

```
    dat$Enc_Key[dat$Diag_Key == 765]
```

Then just select the data by `Enc_Key` and convert boolean to integer:

```
    as.integer( 
      dat$Enc_Key %in% unique(dat$Enc_Key[dat$Diag_Key == 765])
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `mutate` from `dplyr`. May be you have a typo in required output in original data `Enc_Key  = 546` is `765` but not in the required dataframe.

```
 library(dplyr)
 input = read.table(text = "Enc_Key  Patient_Key    Enc_Date    Diag_Key
 123         789         20160512       765
 123         789         20160512       263
 123         789         20160515       493
 546         013         20160226       765      
 564         444         20160707       004
 789         226         20160707       546
 789         226         20160707       765", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

 input %>% group_by(Enc_Key) %>%
     mutate(Diag_Ind = max(grepl('765',Diag_Key)))
```

Output:

```
    Enc_Key Patient_Key Enc_Date Diag_Key Diag_Ind
 1     123         789 20160512      765        1
 2     123         789 20160512      263        1
 3     123         789 20160515      493        1
 4     546          13 20160226      765        1
 5     564         444 20160707        4        0
 6     789         226 20160707      546        1
 7     789         226 20160707      765        1
```

### With corrected typo output is

```
    Enc_Key Patient_Key Enc_Date Diag_Key Diag_Ind
 1     123         789 20160512      765        1
 2     123         789 20160512      263        1
 3     123         789 20160515      493        1
 4     546          13 20160226      723        0
 5     564         444 20160707        4        0
 6     789         226 20160707      546        1
 7     789         226 20160707      765        1
```